# How to add a dropdown list to a word document using python

Tags: python, ms-word, dropdown

I'm currently trying to automate a word generation, and I need to add a dropdown list to the said document.
Is there any way to do that ? I cant figure it out

Comment: you could use pythons docx library: [link](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: Thats what I did, i'm stuck at the creation of the dropdown list, I can't find a way to do it

Comment: You should post your code.

Comment: What code have you tried so far? Do you get any errors?